# TypeError: Cannot read property '$promise' of undefined with using ngResource in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, rest, promise, factory, ngresource

I created a service in my angularJS app with ngResource to send some data to my rest api.

I want to use a promise to perform some tasks with it in my controller just after I sent a request.

Here is my service :

```
angular.module("MyService", ['ngResource'])

.factory("myService",  function ($rootScope, $http, $resource) {

    var apiData = $resource(
        "/api", {},
        {

                  "postQuestion": { method: "POST", url: "/api/:userid"}

        });

        return {

            postQuestion: function(question,  user_id) {
                apiData.postQuestion({ userid: user_id}, question, function(data) {
                    console.log("Sucsess !");
                }, function(error) {
                    console.log("Error " + error.status + " when sending request : " + error.data);
                });

            }
    }
});
```

And here is how I used it in my controller :

```
app.controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope, $filter,  $http, $sce, myService, ngDialog, $rootScope, $location) {


$scope.postQuestion = function(newQuestion)
{

    myService.postQuestion(newQuestion, 1).$promise.then(function(){
        $scope.showNewQuestion = false;
        $location.path("/");
    });
}


})
```

But when running my app, I got this error in my console :

> TypeError: Cannot read property  '$promise'  of undefined
>       at Scope.$scope.postQuestion ...

Don't know why, please help

Comment: Have you tried actually returning the result of apiData.postQuestion from the service method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `postQuestion` function is missing a `return` statement:

```
    postQuestion: function(question,  user_id) {
        //vvvv RETURN the resource object
        return apiData.postQuestion({ userid: user_id}, question, function(data) {
            console.log("Sucsess !");
        }, function(error) {
            console.log("Error " + error.status + " when sending request : " + error.data);
        });

    }
```

When a function omits a `return` statement, it returns a value of `undefined`. Hence the error message:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '$promise' of `undefined` at ...

There is no need to manufacture a promise with `$q.defer()` as the $resource service already returns a promise attached to the resource object as the `$promise` property.

> The Resource instances and collections have these additional properties:
>
> - `$promise`: the promise of the original server interaction that created this instance or collection.
>
> On success, the promise is resolved with the same resource instance or collection object, updated with data from server. This makes it easy to use in resolve section of [$routeProvider.when()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) to defer view rendering until the resource(s) are loaded.
>
> On failure, the promise is rejected with the [http response](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) object, without the resource property.
>
> If an interceptor object was provided, the promise will instead be resolved with the value returned by the interceptor.
>
> [-- AngularJS $resource API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Comment: Yeah, very correct  ! Thank you very much, it's more simple in this way 

Comment: I thought there may be a better way, I haven't dealt much with `$resource`, yes much better approach. Just annoyed that I didn't suggest it, damn!

Answer (score 1):

This function in `myService` isn't returning a promise:

```
postQuestion: function(question,  user_id) {
    apiData.postQuestion({ userid: user_id}, question, function(data) {
        console.log("Sucsess !");
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("Error " + error.status + " when sending request : " + error.data);
    });
}
```

yet the calling code in the controller is expecting one:

```
myService.postQuestion(newQuestion, 1).$promise.then(function(){
    $scope.showNewQuestion = false;
    $location.path("/");
});
```

To fix you can create your own promise using the `$q` library, then resolve or reject it as required and then return that promise to the controller:

```
postQuestion: function(question,  user_id) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    apiData.postQuestion({ userid: user_id}, question, function(data) {
        console.log("Sucsess !");
        deferred.resolve(data);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("Error " + error.status + " when sending request : " + error.data);
        deferred.reject(error);
    });
    return defered.promise;
}
```

Then you can remove`$promise` from the calling code and call the `then` function on the return value of `myService.postQuestion`(which is now a promise):

```
myService.postQuestion(newQuestion, 1).then(function(){
    $scope.showNewQuestion = false;
    $location.path("/");
});
```

Comment: I got this new error :  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined `

Comment: Ah yes,  remove the `$promise` part out of the calling code in the controller. I'll update my post too.